# Copy rows over from an excel file to a new excel file python

Tags: python, excel, pandas, dataframe

I have an excel workbook with 15 different worksheets labeled with a country's name. Inside each worksheet is a bunch of columns for different trade data. What I would like to do is go through each sheet and transfer over the specific columns and data selected. I have a country list that lists out all the countries' names whose rows I want to extract the data from.

So far, the code is copying over the columns that I want and creating 15 new files for each of the countries on the worksheets. However, the rows remain empty

```
import pandas as pd

spreadsheet_file = pd.ExcelFile('C:/Capstone/Data/WITS-Partner_TradePartnersPython.xlsx')
worksheets = spreadsheet_file.sheet_names

countryList = ('Azerbaijan', 'Belarus', 'China', 'Estonia', 'Finland', 'Georgia', 'Kazakhstan', 'Korea, Dem. Rep.', 'Latvia', 'Lithuania', 'Mongolia', 'Norway', 'Poland', 'Ukraine', 'Russian Federation')

#iterate through the different worksheets
for sheet_name in worksheets: 
    df = pd.read_excel(spreadsheet_file, sheet_name)
    #iterate through each country in countryList to be able to select the rows with these country names
    for country in countryList:
        #print(country)
        # create data frame of columns to be extracted with a where clause indicating to only select the rows where the 'Partner Name' column data matches the country name
        df =df[['Partner Name', 'Export Share in Total Products (%)', 'Import Share in Total Products (%)', 'Trade Balance (US$ Thousand)', 'Export (US$ Thousand)','Import (US$ Thousand)']].where(df['Partner Name']==country)
        # get rid of 'NaN' values
        df = df.dropna()
        # copy over dataframe to new excel document
        df.to_excel('C:/Capstone/Data/Trade/Trade_' + country + '_data.xlsx')
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: Hi, what happens if you replace `df =df[['Partner Name', 'Export Share in Total Products (%)', 'Import Share in Total Products (%)', 'Trade Balance (US$ Thousand)', 'Export (US$ Thousand)','Import (US$ Thousand)']].where(df['Partner Name']==country)` with `df = df.loc[df['Partner Name']==country, ['Partner Name', 'Export Share in Total Products (%)', 'Import Share in Total Products (%)', 'Trade Balance (US$ Thousand)', 'Export (US$ Thousand)','Import (US$ Thousand)']]`?